# Screen recording with Blender

Tags: customization, image, video

Is it possible to record a non-timelapse video with Blender's built-in screen recording system? I can't set the capture time under 50ms. That means 2 frames per second.

Comment: thx I hopped there was way

Comment: 50ms would give 20 frames per second, not 2. Perhaps it's too slow writing the screencast to disk, using JPEG as output format might help, but there are more efficient external screen recording programs.

Comment: Blenders screen recording is very limited (you cant see mouse cursor for example), wouldn't suggest to use it for anything besides quick tests.

Comment: thx Brecht I set file type to jpg and that helped a lot.that is still time lapse but it looks much better

Comment: I find there is option to set Blender Window Dimension as pal,etc at start with command_line.I'm no tech guy could you please help me with that.I didn't find anything useful with google

Comment: I've tried to use this feature before, but it's really not worth the trouble. You waste tons of time trying to figure out things that other screen records do by default.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can change the FPS for screencasting in Blender from the System panel of the User Preferences.

1. Go to **File > User Preferences**
2. Switch to the **System** panel.
3. Adjust the *FPS* and *Wait Timer* under the **Screencast** section.

[image]

Comment: those are the default settings *IIRC* and OP asks if he could do it in *realtime*, this still makes it a timelapse.

Comment: Ah my mistake. In that case no, I don't believe you can.

Comment: thx guys and is that software or hardware limitation to takes more screencast per second?Could you recommend any liable software for fair price .

Comment: @Utas your best bet (unless you're on Linux) is probably Camtasia from http://techsmith.com

Comment: @Utas Camtasia is commercial, you can try CamStudio http://camstudio.org/ as an alternative

Comment: @Utas [VLC Media Player](http://www.videolan.org/vlc/) can record the screen, there's an answer about how to do it on the gaming stack exchange [How can I record demos of my gameplay?](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/392/how-can-i-record-demos-of-my-gameplay/112759#112759) You can use it to record the desktop

Comment: wow thats cool I use vlc player every day and  I've no idea it could record vid as well thx man

Comment: OBS takes nice blender videos on Linux

Comment: I can't find this tool following this path. how to use? @JonathanWilliamson

Answer (score 0):

I've tried out Blender's internal screencast, and it gives poor performance and a low framerate. I've had really good success with libav, though:

```
avconv -f x11grab -r 25 -s 1600x900 -i :0.0 -vcodec libx264 -threads 4 "/home/david/Pictures/screencast/Capture $(date -R).avi"
```